# creating two pages for symbols and abbreviations

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am using thesis template from my university as [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/universiti-malaya-thesis-template/kbdmvkbnjchb#.Vgo5y3VSuko).

In this template there is one page specifically allocated for "**LIST OF SYMBOLS AND ACRONYMS**" at the `\frontmatter`.

I want to split this page so that I have two pages instead of one, they are "**LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS**" and "**LIST OF SYMBOLS**"

I have tried to reproduce the two pages with MWE, but I have failed.

Below I provide the MWE which I used.

Can I get some helping hand on this? Appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

%PACKAGES
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % interpret input as unicode
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % choose main font encoding (Cork)
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} %for using striking likes
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%FOR ACRONYM
\RequirePackage{relsize}
\RequirePackage[toc,nonumberlist,shortcuts,translate=false,style=long,acronym]{glossaries}
\RequirePackage{glossaries-babel}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}\SingleSpacing\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\glossarypostamble}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand\listofacronyms{\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]}


%^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
\addto\captionsenglish{%
    \renewcommand*\acronymname{\texorpdfstring{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}{List of Abbreviations}}
    %\renewcommand*\symbolmname{\texorpdfstring{LIST OF SYMBOLS}{List of Symbols}}
}
%^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


\loadglsentries{../umalayaThesisVj/FrontMatters/myacronyms}
%\loadglsentries{../umalayaThesisVj/FrontMatters/mysymbols}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\listofacronyms\clearpage

I want to create a list of symbols used in my thesis. The list has to be pretty much like the list of figures or tables purpose. 



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the contents of your files `myacronyms.tex` and `mysymbols.tex` this is just guesswork, but `\loadglsentries` has an optional argument that indicates which glossary the entries should be added to, however this mechanism only works if the `type` is set to `\glsdefaulttype` in the definitions. This is done by default when you use `\newglossaryentry` (without explicitly using `type`). If on the other hand you use `\newacronym`, the `type` defaults to `\acronymtype`. In this case, the optional argument to `\loadglsentries` is ignored.

This means that if, for example, your `myacronyms.tex` file looks like:

```
\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{long form}
```

then

```
\loadglsentries{myacronyms}
```

should automatically add all the abbreviations to the `\acronymtype` glossary.

If your `mysymbols.tex` file looks like:

```
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name=sample,description=an example}
```

then

```
\loadglsentries{mysymbols}
```

should automatically add all those entries to the default (`main`) glossary.

So, if your `myacronyms.tex` and `mysymbols.tex` files look like the above, then this trimmed-down version of your MWE should work correctly:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[style=long,acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{myacronyms}
\loadglsentries{mysymbols}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=List of Abbreviations]

\printglossary[type=main,title=List of Symbols]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Sample}

Use entries: \gls{abc} and \gls{sample}.

\end{document}
```

If, however, your `myacronyms.tex` file looks like:

```
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{abc}{ABC}{long form}
```

then

```
\loadglsentries{myacronyms}
```

will add your abbreviations to the default (`main`) glossary, which means that all your symbols and abbreviations will be in the same glossary. You should also get a warning message from `makeglossaries`:

```
Warning: File 'test.acn' is empty.
Have you used any entries defined in glossary 'acronym'?
```

(Where the main file is called `test.tex`.)

In this case you need to use the optional argument to `\loadglsentries`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[style=long,acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries[\acronymtype]{myacronyms}
\loadglsentries{mysymbols}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=List of Abbreviations]

\printglossary[type=main,title=List of Symbols]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Sample}

Use entries: \gls{abc} and \gls{sample}.

\end{document}
```